# VuePress - markdown content filled with special characters

Tags: vue.js, vuepress

Attempting to follow along with the [get-started tutorial for VuePress](https://v1.vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/getting-started.html). Upon first running the application, this is what I got:

��#� �H�e�l�l�o� �V�u�e�P�r�e�s�s� � �

I tried changing the text in case it was something weird with PowerShell. This is what I get:

��A�n�y�t�h�i�n�g�

Running node v8.11.4 on Windows 10, just trying to play with the technology.

Comment: The alternating pattern makes me think you've got a two-byte encoding like UTF-16 or UCS2 being treated as an ASCII-based encoding like UTF-8.

Answer (score 3):

Your system may create the file with a different encoding (in my case, windows powershell was using utf-16) - simply change the encoding with your favorite editor.

See https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/issues/276